# Intel compilator for loop speed c

Tags: c, performance, execution-time, icc

I'm struggling to understand why this code runs with blistering speed with Intel compiler 12, and really slows down with Intel compiler 16

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,t;
    int n=10000000;
    int T=1000;
    time_t t1,t2;

    // double A[n],B[n],C[n];
    double *A = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
    double *B = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
    double *C = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*n);



    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       A[i]=1.0;
       B[i]=2.0;
    }
    t1=clock();

    for (t=0;t<T;t++)
       for (i=0;i<n;i++)
          C[i]=A[i]*B[i];

    t2=clock();
    double sum=0.0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) sum += C[i];
    printf("sum %f\n",sum);
    printf("time %f\n",(double)(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

---

- Intel compiler 12: Takes 0.1 second to run on sandy bridge; Intel
  compiler 16: Takes 25 seconds to run on sandy bridge

makefile:
    icc -O2 -o array array.c

Comment: Not related: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Maybe make the `double`s `volatile`?

Comment: Have you tried `-O3` instead of `-O2`?

Comment: Look at disassembly  to find out. This code can be optimized pretty much even manually.

Comment: Have tried with -O3 -parallell

Comment: Look at the assembly output. Show it to us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely, one of the compilers aggressively optimizes away the whole burdensome nested loop. It seems likely that your optimized code actually ends up as:

```
t1=clock();
t2=clock();
double sum=0.0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) sum += A[i]*B[i];
```

It is perfectly fine for the compiler to do such optimizations. You can block optimizations by making the loop iterators `volatile`.

Ensure that you have same level of optimization enabled on both compilers.

Comment: Not speaking of a fact `A` and `B` are constants for all `[i]`... the loops can go away completely.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah this is a simplified example. There will be even more optimizations in the real program, especially at `-O3`.

Comment: Yes. this must be it. adding volatile makes it run the same, compiled with all compilers

Answer (score 2):

The two nested loop are vectorisable providing the compiler is sure that the three areas of memory pointed to by `A`, `B`, and `C` do not alias.  Specifically, that values stored into through `C` can never be read again through `A` and `B` - which would be a hazard if the iterations of the loop ran in parallel, with a load and store order other than that implies in the code.

In the general case, the compiler will not be able to infer this from pointers  returned from a function call, although it may legitimate for it to know about more about the semantics of standard library functions such as `malloc()` than the function signature alone would infer.

It is possible the differences you see are due to change in the strictness of the aliasing rules between compiler versions - or possibly from different default option switches.

Adding the `restrict` qualifier to the pointer declarations tells the compiler that it can assume the that aliasing cannot occur through the use of the pointer, and that the onus lies on the programmer to guarantee this.

```
double * restrict A = malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
double * restrict B = malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
double * restrict C = malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
```